# Google PubSub not working to create a new topic

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api-php-client, google-cloud-pubsub

i'm using the v1-master branch of the PHP API Client library from here:
https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/v1-master/src/Google/Service/Pubsub.php

i'm sure i have all the OAuth stuff right, so assume the $client is already created correctly... also {my-app-id} is replaced with my real application id

```
$pubsub = new Google_Service_Pubsub($client);
$new_topic = new Google_Service_Pubsub_Topic();
$new_topic->setName('projects/{my-app-id}/topics/mytopic');
$topic = $pubsub->topics->create($new_topic);
```

this throws an exception:

```
exception: Google_Service_Exception Object
(
    [errors:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [domain] => global
                    [reason] => invalidArgument
                    [message] => Invalid resource name given (name=projects/{my-app-id}/topics/mytopic). Refer to https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/overview#names for more information.
                )

        )
```

{my-app-id} is just letters a-z, so it is valid and meets all the criteria on the pubsub overview, and i do have rights to the project because if i change the {my-app-id} value, i get a permission denied message.

i've also gone through the API Explorer and got similar broken results:

REQUEST:

```
PUT https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{my-app-id}/topics/mytopic?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

{
}
```

RESPONSE:

```
404 OK

- Show headers -

{
 "error": {
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Requested entity was not found.",
  "status": "NOT_FOUND"
 }
}
```

i've also tried using the master branch of the API client and changing the endpoints to the pubsub.googleapis.com/v1 endpoints rather than www.googleapis.com/pubsub/v1beta1... i even tried v1beta2.  nothing is working.

the PubSub API is enabled for my project, but i can't get any topics created.

does anyone have any PHP sample code of a working app to use the PubSub service?  any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: it seems like the PubSub service moved from v1beta2 to v1, but the client library in the v1-master branch hasn't been updated to reflect those changes... the master branch has all the new v1 endpoints, but doesn't seem to be compatible with App Engine... why is there a master branch and v1-master?

Answer (score 0):

If the API Explorer is also not working, that would indicate that the project id you are specifying in place of {my-app-id} is not correct. It should be a project that has already been created. Visit [https://console.developers.google.com/home/dashboard?project={my-app-id}](https://console.developers.google.com/home/dashboard?project=%7Bmy-app-id%7D) and ensure that you get a dashboard for your project. If not, then that would confirm that the project id is incorrect.